# Lagom http status code / header returned as json

Tags: lagom

I have a sample where I make a client request to debug token request to the FB api, and return the result to the client.
Depending on whether the access token is valid, an appropriate header should be returned:

```
@Override
public ServerServiceCall<LoginUser, Pair<ResponseHeader, String>> login() {
    return this::loginUser;
}

public CompletionStage<Pair<ResponseHeader, String>> loginUser(LoginUser user) {
    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String responseString = null;
    DebugTokenResponse.DebugTokenResponseData response = null;
    ResponseHeader responseHeader = null;

    try {
        response = fbClient.verifyFacebookToken(user.getFbAccessToken(), config.underlying().getString("facebook.app_token"));
        responseString = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(response);

    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | JsonProcessingException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());

    }

    if (response != null) {
        if (!response.isValid()) {
            responseHeader = ResponseHeader.NO_CONTENT.withStatus(401);
        } else {
            responseHeader = ResponseHeader.OK.withStatus(200);
        }
    }

    return completedFuture(Pair.create(responseHeader, responseString));
}
```

However, the result I get is:

[image]

This isn't really what I expected. What I expect to receive is an error http status code of 401, and the json string as defined in the code.
Not sure why I would need header info in the response body.

There is also a strange error that occurs when I want to return a HeaderServiceCall:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a bug, also I am a bit unclear about the difference between a `ServerServiceCall` and `HeaderServiceCall`.

Could someone help?

Comment: Suggest separating your second question into another StackOverflow post. It's not a good practice to ask two questions in one, because then it's harder to find the second one by searching, harder to write one succinct answer, etc. Thanks!

Comment: On closer look, the two questions are related, so you can disregard my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types for [`HeaderServiceCall`](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/current/java/api/com/lightbend/lagom/javadsl/server/HeaderServiceCall.html) are defined this way:

```
interface HeaderServiceCall<Request,Response>
```

and

```
CompletionStage<Pair<ResponseHeader,Response>> invokeWithHeaders(RequestHeader requestHeader,
                                                                 Request request)
```

What this means is that when you define a response type, the return value should be a `CompletionStage` of a `Pair` of the `ResponseHeader` with the response type.

In your code, the response type should be `String`, but you have defined it as `Pair<ResponseHeader, String>`, which means it expects the return value to be nested: `CompletionStage<Pair<ResponseHeader,Pair<ResponseHeader, String>>>`. Note the extra nested `Pair<ResponseHeader, String>`.

When used with `HeaderServiceCall`, which requires you to implement `invokeWithHeaders`, you get a compilation error, which indicates the mismatched types. This is the error in your screenshot above.

When you implement `ServerServiceCall` instead, your method is inferred to implement [`ServiceCall.invoke`](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/current/java/api/com/lightbend/lagom/javadsl/api/ServiceCall.html#invoke-Request-), which is defined as:

```
CompletionStage<Response> invoke()
```

In other words, the return type of the method does not expect the additional `Pair<ResponseHeader, Response>`, so your implementation compiles, but produces the incorrect result. The pair including the `ResponseHeader` is automatically serialized to JSON and returned to the client that way.

Correcting the code requires changing the method signature:

```
@Override
public HeaderServiceCall<LoginUser, String> login() {
    return this::loginUser;
}
```

You also need to change the `loginUser` method to accept the `RequestHeader` parameter, even if it isn't used, so that it matches the signature of `invokeWithHeaders`:

```
public CompletionStage<Pair<ResponseHeader, String>> loginUser(RequestHeader requestHeader, LoginUser user)
```

This should solve your problem, but it would be more typical for a Lagom service to use domain types directly and rely on the built-in JSON serialization support, rather than serializing directly in your service implementation. You also need to watch out for `null` values. You shouldn't return a `null` `ResponseHeader` in any circumstances.

```
@Override
public ServerServiceCall<LoginUser, Pair<ResponseHeader, DebugTokenResponse.DebugTokenResponseData>> login() {
    return this::loginUser;
}

public CompletionStage<Pair<ResponseHeader, DebugTokenResponse.DebugTokenResponseData>> loginUser(RequestHeader requestHeader, LoginUser user) {
    try {
        DebugTokenResponse.DebugTokenResponseData response = fbClient.verifyFacebookToken(user.getFbAccessToken(), config.underlying().getString("facebook.app_token"));
        ResponseHeader responseHeader;

        if (!response.isValid()) {
            responseHeader = ResponseHeader.NO_CONTENT.withStatus(401);
        } else {
            responseHeader = ResponseHeader.OK.withStatus(200);
        }
        return completedFuture(Pair.create(responseHeader, response));
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | JsonProcessingException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        throw e;    
    }
}
```

Finally, it appears that `fbClient.verifyFacebookToken` is a blocking method (it doesn't return until the call completes). Blocking should be avoided in a Lagom service call, as it has the potential to cause performance issues and instability. If this is code you control, it should be written to use a non-blocking style (that returns a `CompletionStage`). If not, you should use [`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-) to wrap the call in a `CompletionStage`, and execute it in another thread pool.

I found this example on GitHub that you might be able to adapt: https://github.com/dmbuchta/empty-play-authentication/blob/0a01fd1bd2d8ef777c6afe5ba313eccc9eb8b878/app/services/login/impl/FacebookLoginService.java#L59-L74

Comment: Amazing, it works. You're right, I was using Future's get, I'll modify that in making the call asynchronous using thenApply. For accessing Facebook I used an unmanaged service to proxy the request. Thanks for the tips, learning a lot here.